# XML Parsing differences between ios 4 and ios 5 ipad

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am having a real hard time understanding something. In the project I've been given, some XML coming from a soap web service is parsed. This works just fine in iOS 4. When I tried to run the code in iOS 5 simulators or a device with iOS 5, the XML is not parsed correctly. It gives `NSXMLParser` domain error code 4.

When I looked at the XML, even in the working OS, the data coming from the webservice has `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of all the XML tags. But that seems to still work in iOS 4. In iOS 5, i get the error mentioned above and a **Bad Request** message. I also couldnt manage to get the returning XML as it is, so far I was only able to see in `NSData`.

I'd like to know if this may be caused by any change in iOS versions, or anything else. I hope I made myself clear. Maybe even with this info, there'll be some answers.

Thanks in advance,
Eren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NSXMLParserError` domain error 4 is `NSXMLParserEmptyDocumentError`. It sounds like the problem lies with the retrieval of the original XML document from the web service and some change between iOS 4 and iOS 5. This should get you started on the right track. Post some code when you can and we can give more information.

Comment: I tried a manually written XML, the code works. So yeah, somewhere between getting the data from the webservice and converting it, the data is broken.

I cant manage to get the data retrieved from the web service other than in `NSData` form. It's in numbers which when parsed, turns to "Bad Request". I am not being fully clear right now, I'll come back refreshed i a few hours. Thanks.

Comment: After some more search, I found that **Bad Request** means a problem with the request. But the request is done via `ASIHTTPRequest` and works **fine** in 4.3. It's done in a rahter complex way for me though, (many different classes, too many variables). What can be missing/changed in 5.0 that will cause this. Any ideas?

Comment: With so many changes between 4.x and 5 and my unfamiliarity with the ASI library, I'm afraid that's almost impossible for me to answer. But now that we know, that it's not the xml parsing, perhaps a new, more focused question will yield some answers.

Comment: I think I'll do that. Thanks.